# how to use lag/lead function in spark streaming application?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql 2.4.x version , datastax-spark-cassandra-connector for Cassandra-3.x version. Along with kafka.

I have a scenario for some finance data coming from kafka topic.
like **companyId, year , quarter , sales ,prev_sales**  data.

```
val kafkaDf = sc.parallelize(Seq((15,2016, 4, 100.5,"")).toDF("companyId", "year","quarter", "sales","prev_sales")
```

I need to prev_sales with previous year same quarter data from cassandra table which is something like below

```
val cassandraTabledf = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (15,2016, 3, 120.6, 320.6),
  (15,2016, 2, 450.2,650.2),
  (15,2016, 1, 200.7,700.7),
  (15,2015, 4, 221.4,400),
  (15,2015, 3, 320.6,300),
  (15,2015, 2, 650.2,200),
  (15,2015, 1, 700.7,100))).toDF("companyId", "year","quarter", "sales","prev_sales")
```

i.e. for Seq((15,2016, 4, 100.5,"") data it should be 2015 year, quarter 4 data i.e. 221.4

so new data is

> (15,2016, 4, 100.5,221.4)

how to do/achieve this one ?
We can do querying explicitly , but is there any way to use "lag" function using join on cassandra table ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Cassandra Spark driver, sorry. Lag should be possible with any spark sql query, AFAIK

Comment: @BdEngineer, Can you provide detail how you are joining dataframe ? and why it required leg function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it required any `leg` and `lead` functions. You can get you desire output by `join` too. Check below code for reference:

**Note: I have added more data in `kafkaDF` for more understanding.**

```
scala> kafkaDf.show(false)
+---------+----+-------+-----+----------+
|companyId|year|quarter|sales|prev_sales|
+---------+----+-------+-----+----------+
|15       |2016|4      |100.5|          |
|15       |2016|1      |115.8|          |
|15       |2016|3      |150.1|          |
+---------+----+-------+-----+----------+


scala> cassandraTabledf.show
+---------+----+-------+-----+----------+
|companyId|year|quarter|sales|prev_sales|
+---------+----+-------+-----+----------+
|       15|2016|      3|120.6|     320.6|
|       15|2016|      2|450.2|     650.2|
|       15|2016|      1|200.7|     700.7|
|       15|2015|      4|221.4|       400|
|       15|2015|      3|320.6|       300|
|       15|2015|      2|650.2|       200|
|       15|2015|      1|700.7|       100|
+---------+----+-------+-----+----------+


scala>kafkaDf.alias("k").join(
                              cassandraTabledf.alias("c"), 
                              col("k.companyId") === col("c.companyId") && 
                              col("k.quarter") === col("c.quarter") && 
                              (col("k.year") - 1) === col("c.year"),
                              "left"
                             )
                       .drop("prev_sales")
                       .select(col("k.*"), col("c.sales").alias("prev_sales"))
                       .withColumn("prev_sales", when(col("prev_sales").isNull, col("sales")).otherwise(col("prev_sales")))
                       .show()
+---------+----+-------+-----+----------+
|companyId|year|quarter|sales|prev_sales|
+---------+----+-------+-----+----------+
|       15|2016|      1|115.8|     700.7|
|       15|2016|      3|150.1|     320.6|
|       15|2016|      4|100.5|     221.4|
+---------+----+-------+-----+----------+
```

Comment: the main issue here is that this is a Spark Join, not optimized join only for necessary data

Comment: @BdEngineer,   I have changed join condition which will handle scenario of "if there is no record for 2015 , quarter 4 , it should populate with 2016, quarter 4's "sales" ". Please check and confirm

Comment: Since this one is close, you can ask new question on stackoverflow  and also provide resulted dataframe and another dataframe with value.

Comment: @BdEngineer i have replied , please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59579922/how-to-pick-latest-record-in-spark-structured-streaming-join