# How to pick latest record in spark structured streaming join

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-spark-dataset

I am using spark-sql 2.4.x version , datastax-spark-cassandra-connector for Cassandra-3.x version. Along with kafka.

> I have rates meta data of currency sample as below :

```
val ratesMetaDataDf = Seq(
     ("EUR","5/10/2019","1.130657","USD"),
     ("EUR","5/9/2019","1.13088","USD")
     ).toDF("base_code", "rate_date","rate_value","target_code")
.withColumn("rate_date", to_date($"rate_date" ,"MM/dd/yyyy").cast(DateType))
.withColumn("rate_value", $"rate_value".cast(DoubleType))
```

> Sales records which i received from kafka topic is , as (sample) below
>   :

```
val kafkaDf = Seq((15,2016, 4, 100.5,"USD","2021-01-20","EUR",221.4)
                                ).toDF("companyId", "year","quarter","sales","code","calc_date","c_code","prev_sales")
```

To calculate "prev_sales" , I need get its "c_code" 's respective "rate_value" which is nearest to the "calc_date" i.e. rate_date"

Which i am doing as following

```
val w2 = Window.orderBy(col("rate_date") desc)
val rateJoinResultDf = kafkaDf.as("k").join(ratesMetaDataDf.as("e"))
                                   .where( ($"k.c_code" === $"e.base_code") &&
                                           ($"rate_date" < $"calc_date")
                                         ).orderBy($"rate_date" desc)
                                  .withColumn("row",row_number.over(w2))
                                  .where($"row" === 1).drop("row")
                                  .withColumn("prev_sales", (col("prev_sales") * col("rate_value")).cast(DoubleType))
                                  .select("companyId", "year","quarter","sales","code","calc_date","prev_sales")
```

In the above to get nearest record (i.e. "5/10/2019" from ratesMetaDataDf  ) for given "rate_date" I am using window and row_number function and sorting the records by "desc".

> But in the spark-sql streaming it is causing the error as below

```
"
Sorting is not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets, unless it is on aggregated DataFrame/Dataset in Complete output mode;;"
```

So how to fetch first record to join in the above.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your last code part with below code. This code will do `left join` and calculate date difference `calc_date` & `rate_date`. Next `Window` function we will pick nearest date and calculate `prev_sales` by using same your calculation.

> Please note I have added one filter condition `filter(col("diff") >=0)`,
> which will handle a case of `calc_date < rate_date`. I have added few
> more records for better understanding of this case.

```scala
scala> ratesMetaDataDf.show
+---------+----------+----------+-----------+
|base_code| rate_date|rate_value|target_code|
+---------+----------+----------+-----------+
|      EUR|2019-05-10|  1.130657|        USD|
|      EUR|2019-05-09|   1.12088|        USD|
|      EUR|2019-12-20|    1.1584|        USD|
+---------+----------+----------+-----------+


scala> kafkaDf.show
+---------+----+-------+-----+----+----------+------+----------+
|companyId|year|quarter|sales|code| calc_date|c_code|prev_sales|
+---------+----+-------+-----+----+----------+------+----------+
|       15|2016|      4|100.5| USD|2021-01-20|   EUR|     221.4|
|       15|2016|      4|100.5| USD|2019-06-20|   EUR|     221.4|
+---------+----+-------+-----+----+----------+------+----------+


scala>  val W = Window.partitionBy("companyId","year","quarter","sales","code","calc_date","c_code","prev_sales").orderBy(col("diff"))

scala>   val rateJoinResultDf= kafkaDf.alias("k").join(ratesMetaDataDf.alias("r"), col("k.c_code") === col("r.base_code"), "left")
                                         .withColumn("diff",datediff(col("calc_date"), col("rate_date")))
                                         .filter(col("diff") >= 0)
                                         .withColumn("closedate", row_number.over(W))
                                         .filter(col("closedate") === 1)
                                         .drop("diff", "closedate")
                                         .withColumn("prev_sales", (col("prev_sales") * col("rate_value")).cast("Decimal(14,5)"))
                                         .select("companyId", "year","quarter","sales","code","calc_date","prev_sales")

scala> rateJoinResultDf.show
+---------+----+-------+-----+----+----------+----------+
|companyId|year|quarter|sales|code| calc_date|prev_sales|
+---------+----+-------+-----+----+----------+----------+
|       15|2016|      4|100.5| USD|2021-01-20| 256.46976|
|       15|2016|      4|100.5| USD|2019-06-20| 250.32746|
+---------+----+-------+-----+----+----------+----------+
```

Comment: I am using partition on all columns of KafkaDF. when we will join it with ratesMetaDataDf there might be one to many join in that case we will have multiple records for single specific row of KafkaDF and need to pick single row record which have closest date. If I use specific column then there is no possibility of uniqueness of single row of KafkaDF. In my KafkaDF if I skip "calc_date" in partition then windows will give single record of both record.

Comment: You can add more columns in Join like year. Which will give less data. I can use min for closedate but at the end we have to check that min value with all date difference. So it is same if I use min or row number.  I have try to remove partition by and uses groupBy but problem is I can do groupBy with all columns companyId,year,quarter,sales,code,calc_date,c_code,prev_sales since prev_sales value will be different after calculation. if I do calculation later then rate_value column will not available. I am still looking for any optimisation if possible, will update if I get anything

Comment: other Solution you can try as writing streaming data into Staging table and do operation over that using another spark job. That depend on how much data you are getting in streaming and how much data in ratesMetaDataDf

Comment: I want one clarity about the case that I have used in answer, is it possible scenario ? I mean will you get past date in calc_date. where they will join with different date from Meta DF. Like for calc_date 2021-01-20 closest date will be 2019-12-20 and for 2019-06-20 closest date will b 2019-05-10. If this is correct scenario then it will difficult to address this issue and if it not then you can pick latest date from Meta table first and join it with KafkaDF which will not required any snuffle (by paritionBy or GroupBy).that will even faster

Comment: Divide KafkaDF into two parts like df = kafkadf.filter(col("A") === col("B")) and df_1 = kafkadf.filter(col("A") =!= col("B")). After it do join with df_1 only and generate df_1_join. In final merge df and df_1_join using Union

Comment: @BdEngineer check my answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59577108/how-to-handle-this-in-spark/59647221#59647221